# SSRS: Define custom X axis position on bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, bar-chart

I have two separate bar charts but I want both to have the same X axis position. That is, I need **both horizontal axis to be at the same height**.

Both charts have the same height, using the properties:

- Chart > Position > Size > Height = equal on both
- Chart Area > Position > Custom Position > Height = 100

[image: axis position] (See the blue arrow)

Software: SSRS 2008R2 (Microsoft Reporting Services)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with this by using the **Chart Area** -> **CustomInnerPlotPosition** and **CustomPosition** values.

I have replicated your issue with a couple of side by side charts. In Design:

[image]

And preview:

[image]

You can see these don't line up, just like yours.

However, if I set the **CustomInnerPlotPosition** values for **Height** and **Top** to be the same for both Charts' Chart Areas, now the bars match in location and height:

[image]

[image]

You will need to tweak the values for your specific setup.

Doug Lane's excellent article [Fit Chart Labels Perfectly in Reporting Services](http://www.douglane.net/fit-chart-labels-in-ssrs/) has much more information on these properties.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! Also thanks for the reference.